# Extracting Content from Email

Tags: php, email, gmail, pop3

I want to develop an application that would extract the following things from an email id,

- A notification about a new email
- Subject
- Sender
- Total Unread emails

Now as I think it wont be easy to extract emails from all of the major email providers so I basically want to do it for Gmail.

I just need to find the way to do it. Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: You can connect to GMail using IMAP and do everything you need. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: what is _code monkey_ question again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually fairly easy using the [PHP IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.imap.php) extension. There are lots of functions there that you can use to list all emails in an inbox, get a count of them. Read their subjects or contents and such.

In GMail labels are the equivalent of folders in the IMAP docs.

You can connect to a GMail like this:

```
$mailbox = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}', 'email_address@gmail.com', $password);
```

Oh! Also you need to log in to GMail on the account you won't to allow email access to, go to Mail Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP-> Enable IMAP

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for the GMail API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/

There will probably be some *code monkeying* involved in fetching the correct data, so I would recommend you to hire a nearby consultant doing it for you.